# 500 server error on php site after deploy using capistrano

Tags: php, deployment, capistrano

I'm using railsless deploy to deploy a sample php application to my server, everything seems to work OK (folders are created and everything is uploaded and symlinked) however when I try to visit the site on my browser I get a 500 internal server error even though there's nothing but an `index.php` file with a "Hello World" string, here's how my config file looks like:

```
set :application, "sample"
set :folder, "projects"

set :repository, "."

set :scm, :none

set :use_sudo, false

set :user, "myuser"
set :domain, "mydomain.com"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
set :port, 2222

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_cache, true
set :copy_compression, :gzip 
set :keep_releases, 4

set :deploy_to, "/home/myuser/public_html/#{folder}/#{application}"

server domain, :app, :web
```

I should be able to see my project when I visit "mydomain.com/projects/sample/current" but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the folders were set with group-write permissions and my host is configured to not show these files but a 500 error instead, removing these permissions fixed the issue.